# Loading Data to Azure Synapse table from Rest API using Azure Data Factory generates NULL records for random records

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have connected to a Rest API using Azure data factory and the API response contains nearly 500 records. The ADF pipeline executes without any issue and populates the data into Synapse table. But some of the records populated in the table are having NULL values instead of the proper api response data.

The stage table generated has all the columns defined as nvarchar(4000)

It happens only for very few records, like 5-6 among the 500 records. The mapping looks good and even the JSON response structure also same for all the response. Is there any solution for the same? Am i missing something related to the MAPPING or table structure?

Comment: is it entering null for single column?

Comment: no for multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and it is coping records successfully for me.

**To get reason for it**

- You can create a table in synapse with not null constraint for all column.
- Then enable logging in ADF to get reason for incompatible rows which entering null values.
  [image]
- It will store the reason for skipped rows which is entering null values in the respective blob storage.